# Indexing content of cell array using cell array of indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cells, cell-array

The question is:
I have a cell array (`MyCellArray`) and a cell array of indices (`IdxCellArray`) of the same size, where each cell contains indices for the corresponding cell of `MyCellArray`.
Is there a way to obtain a cell array output of the elements of `MyCellArray` indexed by  (`IdxCellArray`)?.
`MyCellArray{IdxCellArray}` does not work.

To be precise, assume two cases: in the first one I have a cell array with the following structure:

```
MyCellArray: 2x3
[50x1] [50x1] [50x1]
[76x1] [76x1] [76x1]

IdxCellArray: 2x3
[20x1] [20x1] [20x1]
[21x1] [21x1] [21x1]
```

Where each `IdxCellArray` row marks the same indices. i.e. a `repmat(IdxCellArray(:,1),1,3)` would return exactly `IdxCellArray`.
This is not true for `MyCellArray` where each cell contains a different vector
For the second case I have more generic structures for my arrays:

```
MyCellArray: 2x3
[53x1] [50x1] [52x1]
[75x1] [71x1] [78x1]

IdxCellArray: 2x3
[11x1] [10x1] [21x1]
[15x1] [18x1] [22x1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`cellfun`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
out = cellfun(@(x,y) x(y), MyCellArray, IdxCellArray, 'uni', 0)
```